# Яке правило регулює відмінювання прізвищ на -ой?

Tags: власні-назви, запозичені-слова, відмінювання

Як правильно відмінювати прізища, що закінчуються на -ой, на кшталт Толстой, Фонтлерой, Кривой, Малфой і т.д.? Родовий відмінок має бути Толстоя, Малфоя чи Толстого, Малфого?

Ну і принагідно - як правильно відмінювати ім'я Лєва Толстоя? Яке правило це визначає?

Я розумію, що сучасна традиція передбачає використання російської прикметникової форми для російських прізвищ (-ой як закінчення прикметника) і нормальне відмінювання за правилами для неросійських; але це, фактично, означає, що будь-який носій української мови зобов'язаний знати російську мову настільки, щоб розрізняти малопоширені навіть у Росії прізвища як російські, що є очевидним абсурдом.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Так, відмінювання прізвищ в українській мові вимагає знання контексту:

- *Шевченко* — якої статі? Якщо це чоловік — *Шевченка*, *Шевченку* і т.д.; якщо жінка — не відмінюється. Побачивши в тексті просто «з 20 березня посаду старшого менеджера займає О. Шевченко», Ви не знаєте, як сказати/написати: «з О. Шевченком я жодного разу ще не зустрічався» чи «з О. Шевченко я…».
- *Хижа* (наприклад, *Оксана Хижа*) — в якому сенсі *хижа*? Якщо *[хижа](http://sum.in.ua/s/khyzha)* в значенні *хата*, *комора*, *[хижка](http://sum.in.ua/s/khyzhka)* (іменник) — то *Оксани Хижі*, *Оксані Хижі*, *Оксаною Хижею* і т.д.; якщо ж у неї чоловік *[Хижий](http://sum.in.ua/s/khyzhyj)* (прикметний) — то *Хижої*, *Хижій*, *Хижою* і т.д.
- Таких прикладів можна навести безліч. Тобто ми власні (українські) прізвища в загальному випадку не знаємо як відмінювати. Побачивши в газеті, наприклад, «Диній», Ви не знатимете, як це прізвище відмінювати: *Динього* чи *Динія*.

Те саме, але навіть у більшій мірі із закордонними прізвищами. Так, *Хххой* в загальному випадку в орудному відмінку може бути як *Хххоєм*, так і *Хххим*. Насправді, навіть знання російських слів не допомагає на  100 %, тому що англійське прізвище може виявитися лише схожим на російське. Фактично, як і у випадку нестандартного українського прізвища, на 100 % знати, як воно відмінюється, можна лише знаючи носія.

Якщо під «Лєвом Толстим» Ви маєте на увазі [російського письменника (1828 — 1910)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) (до речі, відповідно до [§ 104.1–2](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par104p1) правопису його ім'я передається як *Лев*), то, оскільки достеменно відомо, що його прізвище є російським прикметником (еквівалентом до *товстий*), то воно й відмінюється як прикметник. Так, в українській мові (наскільки я знаю) немає прикметників на *-ой* (лише на *-ий/-ій*), але, розуміючи, що воно ніяк не може належати до м'якої групи, а також маючи приклад у вигляді займенника *той* (*того*, *тому*, *того*, *тим*, *у тому*/*тім*), відмінюємо його як *Толстого*, *Толстому*, *Толстого*, *Толстим*, *у Толстому* (*Толстім*). Ім'я *Лев*, як зазначено у [примітці 3 до § 103.2](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par103p2prym3) правопису, може відмінюватися і як *Лева*, *Леву* (*Левові*), *Лева*, *Левом*, *у Леві*, *Леве* (аналогічно до відповідного загального іменника), і як *Льва*, *Льву* (*Львові*), *Льва*, *Львом*, *у Льві*. Якщо ж Ви наполягаєте саме на написанні *Лєв*, то Вам залишається лише класичний спосіб відмінювання іменників твердої групи II відміни: *Лєва*, *Лєву* (*Лєвові*), *Лєва*, *Лєвом*, *у Лєві*, *Лєве*.

Якщо ж це якийсь інший/інша *Лєв Толстой*, то теоретично може бути що завгодно. Наприклад, якщо це він, але він не має російських коренів, або має, але з якихось причин відрікається від них і хоче, щоби його прізвище відмінювалося як не російського походження — то *Лєва Толстоя*, *Лєву* (*Лєвові*) *Толстою* (*Толстоєві*), *Лєва Толстоя*, *Лєвом Толстоєм*, *у Лєві Толстої/Толстою*, *Лєве Толстою*. Якщо ж це вона — то ані ім'я, ані прізвище не відмінюються («я вчора ходив на побачення з Лєв Толстой»).

Які конкретно правила це визначають:

- Те, що *-ой* залишається *-ой*, а не передається як *-ий* чи ще якось, зафіксовано у [§ 104.10](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par104p10): «Прикметникові закінчення російських прізвищ передаються так: <…>. Закінчення *-ой* передається через *-ой*: *Донськой*, *Полевой*, *Толстой*.»
- Те, що воно залишається прикметником (відмінюється як прикметник), в принципі, ніде явно не сказано. Особливі сумніви викликає те, що в українській мові начебто немає прикметників на *-ой*. Але, оскільки попередня цитата розташовується під заголовком «Прізвища з прикметниковими значеннями», в якому немає жодного прізвища, що в українській мові явно приймав би не прикметникову форму, то можна припустити, що всі прізвища, описані під тим заголовком, мають прикметникову форму і в українській мові (а не лише в мові оригіналу).
- Відмінювання прикметників описується в [§ 67](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par67). Складність створює те, що там не описано відмінювання прикметників на *-ой* (як я знаю, питомих прикметників на *-ой* в українській мові й немає). Але визначити, що слова на *-ой* мають відмінюватися за правилами твердої групи легко інтуїтивно, бо є вказівний займенник *той* (а також: *отой*, *позатой*), що відмінюється, як прикметник твердої групи.
- Неросійські прізвища на *-ой*, а також російські прізвища на *-ой*, що в оригіналі відмінюються не як прикметники (так, росіяни це самі можуть не знати про чужі прізвища) — логічно припустити, що:

  - чоловічі — відмінюються як іменники м'якої групи II відміни (про належність до II відміни каже [§ 44.II.а](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par44II), до м'якої групи — [§ 45.II.2](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par45IIp2)), тобто за правилами, описаними [на початку § 46](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par46II) та у [§ 48–60](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par48) — з *-я* (а не *-ю*) у родовому відмінку однини (відповідно до [§ 48.2.а](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par48p2a));
  - жіночі — не відмінюються; це очевидно, бо вони не підпадають під жодну відміну, а також це явно сказано у [§ 100.2](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par100p2): «Деякі іменники іншомовного походження не відмінюються, а саме: <…> жіночі імена на приголосний <…>: *Аліс*, *Долорес*, *Зейнаб* <…>.»

Comment: +1, про _Хижа_ дуже класно. А ви знаєте, що Толстой насправді не Лев, а Льов, це через те, що в російській крапки над <ё> можна не ставити. ;)

Comment: @YellowSky, я в курсі. Але традиційно в російській передають його як Лев. Тому й в українську прийшло Лев. (До речі, не факт, що він Льов; його за життя і так, і так називали. Думаю, це теж саме, що, припустимо, про нашу сучасницю через 100 років будуть сперечатися, як її звали — Налаля чи Наталія чи Наталка.)